# Would the target of Enemies Abound change weapons to be more effective?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The description of the [*enemies abound*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enemies-abound) spell (*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 155) states:

> On a failed save, the target loses the ability to distinguish friend from foe, regarding all creatures it can see as enemies until the spell ends. [...]
>
> Whenever the affected creature chooses another creature as a target, it must choose the target at random from among the creatures it can see within range of the attack, spell, or other ability it’s using. If an enemy provokes an opportunity attack from the affected creature, the creature must make that attack if it is able to.

**If I cast *enemies abound* on one of the archers in a tight formation, would they change to a melee weapon to attack without disadvantage?**

Comment: "would they change" makes this opinion-based and circumstantial. Did you mean to ask "could they change"? That's a question that can be answered.

Comment: "Who determines whether a target of the spell changes?" would also work.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer I don't think the question is about the spell's target changing; it's about how the target of the spell can (or might) behave.